# Angular 2 NgFor index before ngxPagination

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the index in ngFor with ngxPagination however the index is always zeroed once it goes to the new page.
What I should do to keep the index counter++

```
<tr *ngFor='let delivery of deliverys   |  paginate: { itemsPerPage: itensPorPagina, currentPage: page } ; let i = index'>
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{delivery?.no_bairro}}</td>
    <td>
      <input (change)="editar(deliverys[i])" type='text' #nu_valor [(ngModel)]='delivery.nu_valor' class='form-control' value="{{delivery?.nu_valor}}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Examples:

[Example 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rmlF.png)

[Example 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6UK8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If starting `page` is 0 , then you can use this :

```
<td>{{(page*itensPorPagina)+i}}</td>
```

---

And if your starting `page` is 1 then

```
<td>{{((page-1)*itensPorPagina)+i}}</td>
```